# How to change text content of multiple html tags using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

For example:

```
<p> 1 </p>
<p> 2 </p>
<p> 3 </p>
```

As you can see that, there are **3 paragraph tag** with the different number. So, using JavaScript read the content of the p tag and changed the text according to the content received from the p tag.

Suppose, first p tag has content **1** so changed it into **"active"**. Second p tag has content **2** so changed it into **"deactivated"** with that third tag contain **3** so changed it into **"others"**.

Where output seems like:

```
<p> Active </p>
<p> Deactivated </p>
<p> Others </p>
```

Even if we changed the p tag order to this:

```
<p> 2 </p>
<p> 3 </p>
<p> 1 </p>
```

the output must be:

```
<p> Deactivated </p>
<p> Others </p>
<p> Active </p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `switch` and `.innerText`

```js
const pEles = [...document.querySelectorAll("p")];

pEles.forEach(ele => {
  switch (ele.innerText) {
    case "1":
      ele.innerText = "Active"
      break;
    case "2":
      ele.innerText = "Deactivated"
      break;
    case "3":
      ele.innerText = "Others";
      break;
  }
})
```

```html
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much as this one help me better to understand

Comment: you can create a hash like  > 
var hash = { '1' : 'Active', '2' : 'Deactivated', '3': 'Others' }  
and then use this hash instead of switch case   like this :  
ele.innerText = hash[ele.innerText]

Answer (score 1):

Use an array with the values you need, for each paragraph convert the original textValue to a number and retrieve the value from the array using that number.

Or use some kind of [templating](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-nmqf7o?file=script.js).

```js
const values = [`Active`, `Deactivated`, `Others`];
document.querySelectorAll(`p`).forEach( (p) =>
  p.textContent = values[+(p.textContent.trim()) - 1]);
```

```html
<p> 1 </p>
<p> 3 </p>
<p> 2 </p>
<p> 3 </p>
<p> 1 </p>
<p> 2 </p>
```